# AWS DNS Traffic forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, amazon-route53

I have the following scenario:
I own the following domain: example.com, which has A record for it: job.example.com/8.8.8.8.

I have purchased an Elastic IP address, and I have changed the A record IP for job.example.com from 8.8.8.8 to AWS Elastic IP address.

What I want to achieve is to hide my "real" office IP. I want when someone visits https://jobs.example.com the IP address behind it will be the Elastic IP address, but some service in Amazon will forward all traffic to my real office IP (8.8.8.8 for example in this question).

I've looked into route53, couldn't find anything.

Please help :)

Comment: I would also recommend CloudFront

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I might get your question wrong but it seems what you're asking for is a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), or more likely in AWS, a [CloudFront CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution.
Considering *CloudFront* pricing, I'd go for that one.

The reverse proxy option would be to setup an *EC2* instance with, for example, the [nginx](http://nginx.org/) server configured like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://8.8.8.8/;
}
```

Depending on your traffic, the later solution could be achieved with a free-tier `t2.micro` instance, which you will begin to be billed for next year.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated